# spring-data-neo4j findAll: Java heap space

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a huge number of users, and use spring-data-neo4j to find all by paging

> Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 15);
>   return userRepository.findAll(pageable);

and I overwrite findAll like:

> Page findAll(Pageable pageable);

But it cause exception, **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

I know the reason must because of the huge number of users, but I confuse why it failed, I've already add pageable param.

Comment: What does your User entity look like? Maybe you are pulling in more nodes because of a@Fetch?

Comment: Yes the implementation of findAll() itself is lazy, also the paging. So it must be something else. Perhaps you can also post the full stack trace.

Comment: just simple java bean, no @fetching